# SQL Query the average, maximum, and total number of rides users have taken

Tags: sql

I need to create a derived table and calculate the avg, max, and total number of rides a user has taken using the travels table. The results should add the distinct USER_ID's to the average rides a user has take, the maximum rides a single user has taken, and the total rides all users have taken.

[image: TRAVELS table]

[Current Query]

```
SELECT
  COUNT(TRAVEL_ID) AS NUM,
  DISTINCT USER_ID  
FROM 
  (SELECT 
          AVG(NUM) AS Average,
          MAX(NUM) AS Maximum,
          NUM AS Total
   FROM TRAVELS) AS a;
```

[Expected Results]

Average 1.5714 | Maximum 2 | Total 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner query count the number of travels for each user using `group by`, after that you can do the final aggregations.

```sql
select
    avg(cnt) as average,
    max(cnt) as maximum,
    sum(cnt) as total
from (
    select 
        USER_ID,
        count(TRAVEL_ID) as cnt
    from TRAVELS
    group by
        USER_ID
) as a
```

Comment: I see, I can only use aggregate functions once created in the derived table then?

Thank you!

Comment: The derived table contains an aggregate function (count) as well. The point here is that you need to get the USER_ID level information first, after that you can do further aggregations. Please let me know if this works or accept my answer if it does.

Comment: Yeah it worked, I was stuck on that for a few hours so I appreciate the help!